# Why does my Next.js code always give me the same Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I keep getting the following Error:
Server Error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

services\index.js (45:33) @ graphqlAPI

```
  43 | `
  44 | 
> 45 | const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);
     |                             ^
  46 | 
  47 | return result.postsConnection.edges;
  48 | }
```

This is my index.tsx:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { PostCard, Categories, PostWidget} from '../components'
import { getPosts } from '../services'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
interface PostNode {
  title: string;
  // include other properties of your post objects
}


export default function Home({posts}) {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="container mx-auto px-10 mb-8"  >
      <Head>
        <title>Blog</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
    </div>
    <div className='grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-12 gap-12 ' >
      <div className='lg:col-span-8 col-span-1'>
      {posts.map((post: {node: PostNode}) => (
  <PostCard post={post.node} key={post.node.title}/>
    ))}
      </div> 
          <div className='lg:col-span-4 col-span-1'>
            <div className='lg:sticky relative top-8'>
              <PostWidget />
              <Categories />
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>

    </>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const posts = (await getPosts()) || [];
  return {
    props: { posts }
  }
}
```

And my index.js:

```
import { graphql } from 'graphql'
import { request, gql } from 'graphql-request'
const graphqlAPI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT;
export const getPosts =  async () => {
    const query = gql`
    query MyQuery {
        assets {
          createdAt
          id
          publishedAt
          fileName
          url
          updatedAt
        }
        postsConnection {
          edges {
            node {
              author {
                bio
                name
                id
                photo {
                  url
                }
              }
              createdAt
              slug
              title
              excerpt
              featuredImage {
                url
              }
              categories {
                name
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `

    const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);

    return result.postsConnection.edges;
}
```

I am currently doing this [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYv55DhgTuA) (54:06), and it doesn't work because of the Error even though it should be correct. My code is slightly different though because ChatGPT tried to fix it but it doesn't make a difference it's the same Error.